# Bash: How to use a secret file for a script?

Tags: bash, automation, secret-key

I've created a really long script which fully automates installation and configuration of a web server in my company. During the script runtime it accesses some remote server using scp and ssh in order to download configuration files and I'd like to be able to have a secret file which holds the password (it's always the same password) and that the script will use this file without the need that i'll insert it manually. some lines from the script look like this:

```
/usr/bin/scp root@192.168.1.10:/etc/mail/sendmail.cf /etc/mail/
/usr/bin/scp -r root@192.168.1.10:/etc/yum.repos.d /etc/

/usr/bin/ssh root@192.168.1.10 'rpm -qa --queryformat "%{NAME}\n" >/tmp/sw.lst'
/usr/bin/scp root@192.168.1.10:/tmp/sw.lst /tmp/
/usr/bin/xargs yum -y install < /tmp/sw.lst
```

I know about the method of `#ssh-keygen` and `#ssh-copy-id` but the problem is that the script will run every time on a different machine and I don't want to exchange the keys before each run.

Comment: Use [SSH keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys) instead using password authentication.

Comment: You didn't read all my question, I said that i'm looking for another method than ssh-keys.

Comment: Generating keys is a one time activity and should be preferred unless you use new systems every time.

Comment: Dude, read my question until the end... It is a different machine every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i had to do something like that, i used `expect` and a wrapper script that would fetch a password from a file.
I.e. in my password file i'd have something like

```
root@192.168.1.10 ThisIsMyPass
user@localhost thisIsMyOtherPass
```

and then have the wrapper script get (it could be simple as `grep "root@192.168.1.10" ~/.passwords | cut -d ' ' -f2`)

Im guessing there are more appropriate methods, but with this one you only need to keep your wrapper and password file protected and you can make your setup script public.

Comment: In order to "paste" the password when needed when scp-ing from a script you need a program called `expect`. More info [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)